# Mathematical operations in while loop

Tags: java

So I have a list of Integers
First index i = what to do, if i = 1 then add, if i = 2 then multiply, if i = 99 then break.
i + 1 and i + 2 are the index of inputs to addition or multiply
i + 3 is the index of where to store result of addition/multiply

Then I step forward 4 more positions, but I'm getting wrong answer, what is wrong here?

```
int i = 0;
       while(true) {
           Integer x = listInteger.get(i + 1);
           Integer y = listInteger.get(i + 2);
           Integer outputindex = listInteger.get(i + 3);

           if(listInteger.get(i).equals(1)) {

               listInteger.set(outputindex, x + y);
           } else if (listInteger.get(i).equals(2)) {
               listInteger.set(outputindex, x * y);
           } else {
               break;
           }

           i += 4;
       }
```

Comment: ```listInteger.get(i + 3)``` doesn't give you the index, it gives you the value at that index. The index is just i + 3.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you meant:

```
Integer outputindex = i + 3;
```

instead of:

```
Integer outputindex = listInteger.get(i + 3);
```